# Restrict user of selecting above 1 MB image from gallery or camera using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to restrict the user of selecting image which is above 1 MB.I got the Image path by using the imagepicker flutter package but can not getting the image size like in KB or MB.please help somebody.

Thanks In Advance
Sourov Bhattacharjee

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have file read access and you can use the following utility function which applies to all kind of files including images

```
checkFileSize(path) {
    var fileSizeLimit = 1024;
    File f = new File(path);
    var s = f.lengthSync()
    print(s); // returns in bytes
    var fileSizeInKB = s / 1024;
    // Convert the KB to MegaBytes (1 MB = 1024 KBytes)
    var fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;

    if(fileSizeInKB > fileSizeLimit) {
       print("File size greater than the limit");
       return false;
    } else {
      print("file can be selected");
      return true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to get the size of the image:
Im.Image image = Im.decodeImage(imageFile.readAsBytesSync());
And then place it in a simple if-else statement.